# Primefaces 4 file uplaod does not invoke method for all event?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

When I upload image 7 files, `primefaces-4` does not invoke listener method for each files. Sometime, 3 or 4 times invoke, not at all.
BTW, If I test primefaces only, it is ok. I also use `omnifaces-1.7`.

```
<p:fileUpload allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" fileUploadListener="#{MyUploadBean.handleAttachment}" 
    id="attachment" mode="advanced" multiple="true" sizeLimit="3000000" 
    update="imageGrid"/>
```

MyUploadBean.java

```
public void handleProposalAttachment(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
    String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
    System.out.println(fileName); <-- Here, I can see some uploaded file name.
}
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{GuestPreferences.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
   <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>    
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>2147483647</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>No Cache Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>No Cache Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlett</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Faces Exception Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Faces Exception Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.ace.java.web.common.BootStrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Lib and server is `Jboss 7.1.1`

```
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
primefaces-4.0-20130910.075046-7.jar
portlet-2.0.0.jar
portlet-api-2.0-r12.jar
gmultipart-0.2.jar
omnifaces-1.7.jar
```

Comment: Follow this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imiBwk_xqaE

Answer (score 0):

hy,
i have try it, it 's work for all files no problem,
i think your problem is: you have put `<p:fileUpload>` and another tag in some form,
try to put `<p:fileUpload>` in form alone it s work fine :)
dont forget to update the form of fileUpload and the form of image.
try it, i wait if it's ok,
if don't work put all your page

Comment: I have one tag in the form